# Outdoor faucet assembly

Tags: plumbing

[image][image][image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjvke.jpg)[image]Are looking to replace this pc of our outdoor garden faucet.hoe do I identify the correct one to purchase? No identifying marks on here and is corroded.

Comment: Most of them come in standard sizes.  Usually the best way for matching/replacement is to take it to local hardware/plumbing/big box store.

Comment: You're missing the bottom piece.

Comment: Went to the big box store, nothing there that I could see. Plumbing supply is open Monday will have to wait. Thank you

Comment: Rest of piece is in the wall. Just want this pc would have to take down some Sheetrock inside to do the inside and is very tight. Hoping to avoid

Comment: Picture of the wall where the spout is please?

Comment: The existing unit doesn't appear to be of the "frost proof" variety, but you should consider that possibility when buying a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a Webstone Corporation spigot valve. It's surprising *"big box"* didn't have a suitable replacement, as plumbing is pretty standardized when it comes to fittings.

Using a rag or old toothbrush dipped in soapy water, clean the female threads at the wall and use teflon plumbing tape or pipe dope and wrap or brush the  threads on the new handle and only tighten until snug without having to force it.

Turn on the water for a few seconds and check for leaks.

Comment: The partially obliterated word on top is not consistent with BOSTON - ...BSTON or possibly ...BSION or ...EBSTON or ...EBSION if that's an E where things go to heck at the beginning of the word.

Comment: Appears to be more likely WEBSTONE CORPORATION   http://www.webstonevalves.com

Comment: I didn't have my coffee yet. That was a silly oversight. Thanks @Ecnerwal

Comment: Was able to replace rubber washer and, along with the Teflon tape, that stopped the leak for now. Could not get handle off the pc. Maybe I missed in the “big box” store. Saw all sorts of valves, just not the innards, which, along with the knob in the photo, is all I really want to replace at the moment. Obviously not a pro, so thanks for the help!

Comment: Usually The bib (piece with spout) the valve, and handle usually come as a single unit. Best go to plumbing store as planned.

Comment: Most definitely. Thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: Saw new picture. Definitely don't want to mess with the part on wall, I did once on a 1950's refit. And the iron pipe snapped off inside the wall.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to replace the stem , bonnet and disc ; slim to none chances of finding a new one. You will need to replace the whole valve; or I would refurbish the valve as @ G Warner  answered. That looks like a well made old bronze valve, today you will get brass junk or plastic in a new valve.  Several years ago, my new "made in China" gate valve failed on second use ( the brass gate actually fell apart, casting defect). It was the second block valve in my sprinkler system so I could just close it up and leave it in place.